# Implementing a Mailing List (Need to Send an Email From Another Account)

Tags: list, email, mailing

I am trying to implement a mailing list. Right now, I am able to receive emails and automatically send emails from by gmail.

However, normal mailing lists will effectively spoof the original sender of emails.

For example, suppose that `alice@gmail.com, bob@gmail.com`, and `eve@gmail.com` are on the mailing list.

If Alice sends an email to the list, I would want to send the email as `alice@gmail.com`, even though I don't actually have access to this email.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

the easy way is just just add "reply-to" to the message with the original sender